# Select List, 'Other" option text field, any text written in textfield 'Illegal Value' error is given

Tags: 6, entities, nodes

In one of my content types, I have an option for a select list with pre-defined values. I have the 'other' field configured, so when selected a text field displays to enter the 'other' information.

However whenever a user enters information into the text field and attempts to save the form, an "Illegal Value" error is displayed.

I went in and looked at the configuration and could not see anything wrong. Any ideas?

[image: Screenshot of Select List configuration]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using http://drupal.org/project/select_or_other ?

Is the field set as required? Take a screen pic of the config for the field.

Comment: No not using select_or_other, just a CCK select field. I uploaded an image to the original post which you can see above.

Comment: Actually, Westie is correct. I forgot I had installed Select or other module. The problem was I was using an outdated version of the module which was creating a validation error. Once I installed the update, all worked well. Thanks!